# What is the correct way to say "either with John or myself"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, syntactic-analysis, grammatical-case, reflexives

Which of the following is correct? (This is to confirm the number of people for an event I am hosting with someone else.)

> A. Until then, if you all could confirm your attendance [either] with John or myself [,] it'd be highly appreciated.
>
> B. Until then, if you all could confirm your attendance with [either] John or me [,] it'd be highly appreciated.
>
> C. Until then, if you all could confirm your attendance with [either] John or I [,] it'd be highly appreciated.

Do I need *either*, and a comma as well?

Comment: Note: this is not a reflexive pronoun. C is grammatically incorrect; both A and B are grammatically correct, A is just more emphatic than B.

Comment: So, _myself_ is a reflexive pronoun, sometimes; and then there are instances of _myself_ that aren't reflexive pronouns? How can one tell the difference?

Comment: As this sounds like a pretty formal event, I would suggest A and to and write the full form: "it would be highly appreciated".

Comment: Personally, I don't like "if you all could confirm": I'd write "if you could all confirm" - But I'm British & maybe the other is more common in AmE. I would also omit "either".

Comment: @TrevorD If in the Southern US, *you all* would be much more acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Some people do use the reflexive pronoun *myself* as in A, but it isn’t normally necessary. *Me*, as in B, is enough. The use of *I*, as in C, is frequently found, but many people don’t like it, so it’s best avoided if you think your readers will be among them.

*Either* isn't necessary, but a comma before *it'd* will help readers, because it shows the start of a new clause.

Comment: I would suggest *I* is wrong. It is being used as the object of a preposition which requires an objective case pronoun.

Comment: You might like to take a look at page 9 here: http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam033/2001025630.pdf where the authors of ‘The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language’ consider the example ‘They invited my partner and I to lunch.’ As they say, ‘why should we simply assume that the grammatical rules for case assignment cannot differentiate between a coordinated and a non-coordinated pronoun?’

Comment: A brief review of the paragraph is interesting, but gives no explanation or structural guidance as to why it's acceptable as standard English except to say listeners can distinguish between singular and plural constructions (and imply listeners can understand alternate rules), but they do not explain any standard rule.

Comment: Elsewhere they write that constructions like ‘They invited Sandy and I’ are ‘used by many highly educated people with social prestige in the community; it should be regarded as a variant Standard English form.’

Comment: I do appreciate the avoidance of rigidity (which is futile eventually because language has to grow) but how do you distinguish between common ungrammatical mistakes and evolving acceptable change?

Comment: Too big a question to pursue here perhaps, but Henry Sweet, writing in 1891, was on the right lines: 'In considering the use of grammar as a corrective of what are called "ungrammatical" expressions, it must be borne in mind that the rules of grammar have no value except as statements of facts: whatever is in general use in a language is for that very reason grammatically correct.'

Answer (score 1):

Although there are people who accept form A, I think most educated native English speakers consider it a solecism. The simplest, safest rule is that if you think you could either say "me" or "myself" then you should say "me."

And, yes, I think you want that comma.

Comment: Use of a reflexive pronoun in a place where a normal personal pronoun would work always seems to me to reflect an attempt to be more formal simply by using formal words more often than usual, rather than by using words correctly in formal constructions. Rather like asking _Whom shall I say is calling?_ because _whom_ is a more formal word than _who_.

Answer (score 0):

Your invitation does not need the word "either." The comma preceding "it'd" is grammatically correct. And "B" is the only correct version. The pronoun "me" is used in a prepositional phrase. The word "myself" is very often misused -- by uneducated and college educated people alike. See "The Goof-Proofer" by Stephen J. Manhard or "Goof Proof Grammar" by Felice Primeau Devine to learn the correct usage.

Comment: Welcome! If you could give a specific quote from either of your cited sources, we could compare it with the advice given by some others which suggests that (A) also may be appropriate. That would round out the answer.